# Run PhantomJS with Eclipse GAE

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, google-app-engine, phantomjs

I am facing a problem in running PhantomJS with Eclipse App Engine-JAVA. It is working fine with Command Prompt since I have set the path for PhantomJS in my environment variables. Please help me.

How can I put PhatomJS on my classpath or buildpath in eclipse so that It is available on the web-browser, because if I use the script in my HTML, is shows error that undefined variable phantom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use PhantomJS with Google App Engine.
PhantomJS is a Headless WebKit (with JavaScript API) it is written in C++.
GAE does only support Java (Java Byte Code), Python and GO.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837692/3618671):

> Google App Engine supports a number of language runtimes (Java, Python, PHP and Go), but you can use the [Managed VMs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33837692/3618671) feature of Google App Engine to run anything in a Docker container (such as PhantomJS), and you can also use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) to get a VM where you can also install anything you would like, in any language.
>
> For reference, here's [a tutorial for running Node.js on Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/) to help guide you in the right direction.