# Phantomjs integration with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, phantomjs

Hi I like to know if it is possible to run phantomjs on Google App Engine.

My use case is to use Phantomjs to take snapshots of html pages served on GAE using a cron job.

Has this been done before ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Run PhantomJS with Eclipse GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807709/run-phantomjs-with-eclipse-gae)

Comment: There is no phantomjs under [Services](https://developers.google.com/appengine/training/intro/whatisgae?hl=de#services), so no you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

Google App Engine supports a number of language runtimes (Java, Python, PHP and Go), but you can use the [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) feature of Google App Engine to run anything in a Docker container (such as PhantomJS), and you can also use [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) to get a VM where you can also install anything you would like, in any language.

For reference, here's [a tutorial for running Node.js on Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/) to help guide you in the right direction.

Alternatively, [Google Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) lets you run arbitrary stateless containers pn a serverless platform, so you can run your PhantomJS app there if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run phantomjs on Google App Engine.

> Currently, Google App Engine supports Java, Python, PHP, and Go. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/?hl=en)

As @artjom-b mentioned you can use some services that aren't written in the supported languages (like memcache), but phantomjs is not one of them.

If you are asking about testing an application that you are building on Google App Engine, it is possible to run phantomjs tests against a google app engine application. You would just need to run phantomjs on a different service, such as an EC2 instance.

Comment: You can use Google App Engine [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) to run software in any other language; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33837692/3618671) for details.